# Highlight the three last updated files in ls output

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, ls

Is there any way to overload or wrap the `ls` command so that it will highlight / underline / otherwise make obvious the last three modified files?

I know that I can simply `ls -rtl` to order by reverse modification time, but I usually do need an *alphabetical* list of files despite the fact that I would like to quickly identify the last file that myself or another dev modified.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following seems to work for me

```
 grep --color -E -- "$(ls -rtl | tail -n3)|$" <(ls -l)
```

It uses grep with highlight on input `ls -l` and uses a regular expression to search for either of the inputs for the three oldest command. It also search for the end-of-line `$` in order to print the whole file.

You can also put it in a function, such that you can use `lll *` with multiple arguments, just as you would use `ls`

```
function lll ()
{
    command grep --color -E -- "$(ls -rtl $@ | tail -n3)|$" <(ls -l $@)
}
```

Comment: +1: That's *much* nicer than the crazy one-liner I eventually came up with: `ls -l | grep --color=ALWAYS -C 1000 -E \`ls -rt | tail -n 3 | perl -0777 -e '$x=join("|",split(" ",<>));print $x'\``

Comment: That is ridiculously epic. :D

Comment: Awesome work. I'll note that if you try this in a directory that contains less than three files, then I get a "grep: Invalid range end" error.

Comment: I'm running this with `lsl` (`ls Last`) and it is absolutely fantastic. What a difference this makes in huge directories. Again, thank you!

Comment: @dotancohen You're welcome, thanks for the challenge :)

Comment: `function lll ()
{
    command grep --color -E -- "$(ls -rtl $1 | tail -n3)|$" <(ls -l $1)
}` With this function, you can give a directory as argument, i.e. `lll /home` @dotancohen

Comment: Thank you, I was actually already doing that, like this: `grep --color -E -- "$(ls -rtl $@ | tail -n3)|$" <(ls -l $@)`

Answer (score 4):

It won't highlight the last three modified files (which I think is quite a difficult thing to achieve reliably), but [`ls++`](https://github.com/trapd00r/ls--#readme) might be enough for what you want. It highlights files by relative age, grouping by colour files that are seconds, hours, days or months old.

[image: ls++ screenshot]

You can configure the colours to make the timescale you tend to work on more apparent (for active coding, hours vs days is the most important cross-over point for me).

Comment: Nice, thanks. However, I'm usually SSHing into servers that I cannot install packages on.

Comment: @dotancohen It's a single perl script, you should be able to install it in to your home directory (`~/bin` or something, add to your PATH in profile) - though this won't work if there are dependencies that are not installed.

Comment: I see, thanks Random! In fact I usually do have things in `$HOME/bin/`.