# Different colour for the KiB range in `ls -l`

Tags: bash, ls

Is there any sane way to highlight the 4th, 5th, and 6th columns from the right of the file size in `ls -l`? My intention is to make it easy to read a file size be it in bytes, KiBs, or MiBs. I do know about the `-h` flag, but I find that having to interpret the letters at the end is more cumbersome than just looking and seeing the length of the number (magnitude). This is the same reason why race cars use analogue dials instead of digital.

My target shell is Bash. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I am looking to highlight the thousands, ten thousands, and one hundred thousands places of the size column. Like this: 123**456**789

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49270/14084

Comment: Thanks, Bernhard! I do use your solution to that question every day, I have `lsl` aliased to it with some minor changes. In fact, the answer to this question will be combined with your technique there in my `lsl` alias.

Comment: @dotancohen Ah, didn't realize it was the same guy asking the question, but I was actually referring to this ls++ answer here :)

Comment: I see. ls++ doesn't address this issue, unfortunately.

Comment: @Bernhard: It still needs some tweaking, but take a look: `grep --color -E -- "$(ls -rtl $@ | tail -n4)|$" <(ls -l $@ | perl -pe 's{^((?:\S+\s+){4}\d*)(\d{3})(?=\d{3})}{$1\e[31;1m$2\e[m}')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
ls -l | perl -pe 'BEGIN{@color=(0,2,3,1,5,4)}
  s{((?:\S+\s+){4})(\d+)}{"$1\e[3" . 
  $color[log($2||1)/log(2)/10] . "m$2\e[m"}e'
```

For black (or whatever the default foreground colour is on your terminal) for sizes from 0 to 1023, green from 1k to 1M, yellow for 1M to 1G, then red, purple, blue.

**Edit**. Based on your edited requirements:

```
ls -l | perl -pe 's{^((?:\S+\s+){4}\d*)(\d{3})(?=\d{3})}
                   {$1\e[31;1m$2\e[m}'
```

Comment: Cool! I presume one would want to have an alias for that though? :)

Comment: Thanks. It is not what I'm looking for (I'll clarify the question) but it is certainly helpful and I just learned a bunch of perl from it!

Comment: Very nice! And thank you for teaching me some perl!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way withou installing any additional software is to `grep --color` whatever you want. To highlight filesize from ls output you should run something like that (sometimes it will highlight not only size):

```
ls -l | grep --color '\s\+[0-9]\+\s'
```

Othwerwise please refer to the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267400/colour-highlighting-output-based-on-regex-in-shell/4269167#4269167) on SO.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, highlighting the number is not what I am looking for. I have clarified the question. In any case, +1 due to teaching me something new!